# rest assured json path response validation is not working as expected when key in json is having dot operator

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

**How can I get the value of key organization.email using restassured jsonpath from below json response**

```
 {
    "organization.email": [
        "The organization.email has already been taken."
     ]
 }
```

This is the Rest assured testng code used.

```
package com.api.tests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
public class JsonTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        String jsonString = "{\r\n"
                + "    \"organization.email\": [\r\n"
                + "        \"The organization.email has already been taken.\"\r\n"
                + "    ]\r\n"
                + "}";
        JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.from(jsonString);
        String value = jsonPath.getString("$['organization.email'][0]");
        System.out.println("value is:"+value);
    }
}
```

The value of string variable value is showing as null in ide console. Verified
the json path in many json path online websites and it is correct. But the key value
is  printing as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose one of these below approaches.

```
jsonPath.getString("'organization.email'[0]");
```

or

```
jsonPath.getString("get('organization.email')[0]");
```

or

```
jsonPath.getString("getAt('organization.email')[0]");
```